# How can I Highlight the current page in nav?

Tags: javascript, php, html, navbar, bootstrap-5

This is my code for account.php.
**I am using bootstrap 5,** and I can't figure out why my history and ranking tabs are not getting highlighted in the navbar after clicking.

I tried using javascript and jquery functions provided in similar answers.
None of them are working.

```js
$(".nav-item .nav-link").on("click", function() {
  $(".nav-link").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="account.php?q=1">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="account.php?q=2">History</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="account.php?q=3">Ranking</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <form class="d-flex">
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 28px;" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-nav a");
console.log(a);
for (var i = 0, length = a.length; i < length; i++) {
  a[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log("OK");
    var b = document.querySelector(".navbar-nav li a.active");
    console.log(b);
    if (b) b.classList.remove("active");
    this.classList.add('active');
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="account.php?q=1">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="account.php?q=2">History</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="account.php?q=3">Ranking</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <form class="d-flex">
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 28px;" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: I made you two snippets. Please make them show the nav bar (it  is collapsed)

Comment: _"why my history and ranking tabs are not getting highlighted in the navbar after clicking."_ - because they are loading a _new page_, which means anything you try to do with JS in the _current_ page, of course gets replaced immediately afterwards.

Comment: but I am sending the parameters to the same php file(account.php).

Comment: Can I add the script inside  <?php
          //history start
          if (@$_GET['q'] == 2) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".navbar-nav li a").function() {
              $(".navbar-nav li a").removeClass(active);
              $(this).addClass(active);    
            };
            </script>';